# Flex iOS <application> failed to install

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air

I have created an flex app. Now I want to export it on iOS. Then I have download the profile and certificate from developer.apple.com and created the .ipa file but when I install the application on device it gives me

failed to install

Please Help I am stuck...

Comment: which profile you created, is it development profile or distribution profile?

Comment: I have tried both the profile. first development and then adhoc distribution profile.

Comment: are you sure your ipa is packed using the adhoc distribution profile and also your device UDID is in the profile?

Comment: Check your bundle identifier and make sure you configured your profile in Target->Build Settings..

Comment: Did you add your device to developer portal by logging in through your account?

Comment: check out this article: http://devgirl.org/2011/06/20/flexair-for-ios-development-process-explained/

Comment: also you should get familiar with testflightapp.com, and make sure that both ipad and iphone version is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I have not selected any certificate from the profile. This resolves my issue.